# get_results using wpdb

Tags: database, query, wpdb

I'm trying to retrieve information on my database. I wanted to display all `pages` using this statement, but I'm getting a blank `ARRAY`

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results (
        "
        SELECT * 
        FROM  $wpdb->wp_posts 
        WHERE post_type =  'page'
        "
        );

echo $result; // display data
```

Output:

```
  ARRAY
```

**EDIT**: After changing below suggestions, I'm now using this. but I still don't get any results:

```
global $wpdb;

    $posts = $wpdb->wp_posts;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( " SELECT * FROM  $posts WHERE 'post_type' =  'page' "  );

    foreach ($result as $page) {
            echo $page->ID.'<br/>';

    }
```

Comment: Try wrapping `$wpdb->wp_posts` with curly braces, ie. `{$wpdb->wp_posts}`..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
global $wpdb;

$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "
    SELECT * 
    FROM  $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_type = 'page'
" );

foreach ( $result as $page )
{
   echo $page->ID.'<br/>';
   echo $page->post_title.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: hi @balamurugan, i tried your answer but im still not getting any results. you can see my [EDIT] part above.

Comment: actually what u r getting and do u remove ... from my code. i tested it and getting all page id

Comment: im using my [edit] part as seen above my original post.
i tried `echo $result` just to make sure that im retrieving data from the `query` what i get is print `Array`. when i use `echo $page->ID` i dont get anything. im really not sure why..

Comment: you just simply copy & paste that code completely. That's all to do to get the result.

Comment: yes, it worked! when i try to review my code and yours, the only difference i saw is this part `$tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'posts';` this part wasnt in the codex documentation. can you explain to me why it works?

Comment: $wpdb->prefix = wp_ ( as in database table prefix) which will be as wp_posts in database. in future u can give yourname as prefix. so that it will not affect this kind of code. And try always use this way.

Answer (score 5):

You have a slight misunderstanding:

When calling `$wpdb`, you get a list of properties that contain the core names of the tables:

```
// The custom prefix from wp-config.php
// only needed for custom tables
$wpdb->prefix

// Tables where you don't need a prefix: built in ones:
$wpdb->posts
$wpdb->postmeta
$wpdb->users
```

So your final query would look *like* this:

```
$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = 'page'" );
```

Comment: +1 for this, thank you. but i needed to give credit the person who responded to me first, he already provided the correct answer, i was just wasnt able to follow his instruction.

Comment: Sure. Sidenote: As I stated, the `$wpdb->prefix` shouldn't be used for built-in tables. Just call them directly. Fixed this is his answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. I faced the similar problem and solved it by removing $wpdb from 'FROM' field.

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results (
            "
            SELECT * 
            FROM  wp_posts 
            WHERE post_type =  'page'
            "
            );

echo $result; // display data
```

Answer (score 0):

By "blank Array" do you mean an 'empty array' or is the output 'ARRAY'. If it's the latter then, it is the expected output. You need to loop through that array and display results accordingly.

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results